# Ambiguous pywintypes.error when calling win32gui.GetPixel()

Tags: python, ambiguous, getpixel, win32gui

So here's the line of code triggering the error:

```
win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(self._hwndGame), x, y)
```

Here's the error:

```
pywintypes.error: (0, 'GetPixel', 'No error message is available')
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error or where to begin resolving it. Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I may have accidentally solved my problem. It seems the error (in this case) is thrown when trying to GetPixel() for a device that doesn't support "color management." Either that or I was trying to GetPixel() outside the bounds of the window's dimensions. Both cases seemed to cause this error. This is just a hunch as to how I solved it.